# Confusion about a problem on electrical potential energy

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I'm a high schooler doing a question as follows:
"An electron moves from point A where the potential is 100.0 V to point B where the potential is 200.0V.The electron started from rest. Calculate the speed of the electron as it passes the point B."

The solution is to equate the work done on electron to kinetic energy gained by the electron.

However, I don't understand how the law of energy conservation still holds here? Both electron's potential energy and kinetic energy has increased. Work is being done on the electron, but as far as I understand it's just supposed to move the electron to a higher potential, right? In order to give it some velocity, don't you have to put in some extra energy?

Comment: Hint: The electrons charge is $q = -|e|$, its potential energy in an electrostatic potential $\phi$ is $q \phi$.

Comment: OHH does that mean that the potential energy has decreased? I always assumed that it is moving from 100V to 200V is moving away from the original charge, but it is actually moving towards that charge and losing potential, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you assume the potential is created by a positive charge, then the electron is moving towards it (and loses potential energy).

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the electron at your initial time. It has a certain total energy $E = K_1 + U_1$ where $K$ is kinetic energy and $U$ is potential energy.

Is the system's total energy changing with time? To answer this ask yourself: Is there any non-conservative force acting on the electron? If the answer is no, then the system's total energy is not changing with time and energy conservation holds.

You say that in order to increase the kinetic energy (velocity) of the electron energy needs to be put in. This is certainly not true. In your initial situation you already have some potential energy which can be converted into kinetic energy. Hence, no additional energy would necessarily have to be added into the system.

Comment: If the potential energy were to be converted into kinetic energy, the potential energy would decrease. So the potential energy of the electron has decreased?

Comment: Total energy of the system does not change with time means that energy is conserved. Thus, when our electron starts with only potential energy and no non-conservative work is done on this electron energy is conserved. Thus, if we observe a change in potential energy, the total energy must not change. Thus, the decrease in potential energy must mean that some other quantity of energy increased. In this case that other quantity of energy that must have increased is kinetic energy. @Hengjiaren

Comment: That makes so much sense, thanks!